# Editing substring with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need find substring in text and edit it with sed.

For example:

```
...qwerty/asdfgh/zxc...
```

Is it possible to find this substring with sed and edit it in

```
...------/------/---...
```

or better use something other for this problem?
Unfortunately, i can't find info about editing founded substring with regex in sed.

Comment: There may be a way to do it, but it's probably far easier with `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` would do, as long as you don't have special characters

```
echo "...qwerty/asdfgh/zxc..." | sed 's_qwerty/asdfgh/zxc_------/------/---_'
```

Answer (score 0):

If string in a bash variable, you can use:

```
var="...qwerty/asdfgh/zxc..."
echo "${var//[a-z]/-}"
```